# Argentinian working remotely for the US by contract, trying to move to The Netherlands, but how?

Tags: working-visas, resident-permit, netherlands, argentine-citizens

this is my first post here. I was kinda hesitant on posting the question because I think I exhausted every channel already, but I guess I don't lose anything by "just asking" and know your experiences.

For the past three years I've been living in Brazil (I have a permanent visa now), and for the past two I've been **working remotely for a US company**, the contract has **no expiration date**, and it's a company where I can stay for years, so it's **pretty stable**.  **My income** (in USD), before taxes, is **above the average**. And I work as a System Engineer (Although I don't have a degree) consultant. I'm 31 years old.

According to my family, I have Austrian roots, but all the documentation was lost between WWI and WWII, so there's no way I can prove that (believe me, I've tried)

Because of the Mercosur, I can stay in Brazil as long as I want, but **I really want to move to The Netherlands**, Amsterdam to be more specific, it's a city I love, and I've been there around 6 times, so there's little surprise for me in the day to day basis (meaning that I already have an idea on how a "normal life-not tourist" would be).

I've been to the immigration services in Amsterdam last time I went there and tried to get as much information as possible, and the only two things I've got in clean (to get a resident visa) were these:

1. If I want to enter The Netherlands as a hard worker guy, I need to fill a lot of paperwork, **present myself as a start up**, present and idea and a plan to the government and tell them how new and fresh my company idea is, what's in it for The Netherlands government, a detailed economy plan, how many Dutch employees I plan to have, a Dutch business partner, and a big list of etceteras that, honestly, sounds bizarre. Not to mention that the government will accept around **100 applications per year** and they'll review them all and let around 10 of those applications in. So it's basically a no.
2. **Get a partner**, any partner, no matter the gender, register under the same address, show the government that you live together, **no need to marry her/him**.

Now, on my next trip, coming next September, **I'll be staying almost three months in Amsterdam** (tourist visa is 90 days max for me), so I'll be trying to achieve point 2 while I look for an alternative, since point 1 looks impossible. I'm just a simple consultant and I don't have the infrastructure of a *Start up*.

I never thought this was going to be easy, but never it was going to be this hard!

And **my question is**: Does it really come to this for me? Considering I have stability, I work remotely, I have a good salary, I'm single (so no strings attached), I want to do everything **the legal way**, isn't there another way?

**Thanks a lot in advance for reading this and for any replies you post here!**

Comment: I have heard of many people registering businesses to move to the Netherlands.  They did not have a lot of resources.  This was many years ago, so the rules may have changed; I do not know.  As to the partner route, you don't need to marry the partner, but you do need to learn Dutch and meet several other requirements *before you are allowed to move to the Netherlands,* so this seems like a pretty burdensome option.  Many people will be disinclined to trust you as a potential partner, fearing that you are using them for the immigration benefit.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are other options to work here. I know there are umbrella companies that can hire you and get part of your money from US company to make your stay legal here.

So it will look like they make a contract with US company and hire you to do it.

Not all of then will arrange you a permit. But should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay in The Netherlands, or anyway else in EU, the consequence is, you'll became a **tax resident** there. The consequence - you must be taxed there! No way around it, anything you find out, even if it seems legit at the beginning, could eventually cost you a lot.

So there are 2 option: either the company you work for register her filiae in The Netherlands, or you work for her through other company registered there 
or you register as contractor - which means opening your own company - more paper work and because you trade with offshore partner, more things could go wrong and cost you a lot of money (wrongly filled declaration, wrongly classified income etc. - you need a good bookkeeper).